# При изменения значений option в теге select нужно что бы вставился текст еще в 3 поля ниже

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача такова: При выборе значение в теге Select должно записываться еще 3 поля ниже, конструкция должны быть через switch. Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Пример моего кода:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {


        var val = $('#target').change(function (event) {
            alert($('#target option:selected').val());
        });
        var firstlable = '';
        var secondlable = '';
        var thirdlable = '';
        switch (val) {
            case 1:
                $('#firstlable').html("<span class='red'>Hello <b>Again</b></span>" );
                break;

        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select  name="form" id="target">
  <option value="0">Пункт 1</option>
  <option value="1">Пункт 2</option>
  <option value="3">Пункт 2</option>
  <option value="4">Пункт 2</option>
  <option value="5">Пункт 2</option>
 </select>
 <p id="firstlable"></p>
 <p id="secondlable"></p>
 <p id="thirdlable"></p>
```

Comment: Ничего не понял.. Какой текст?

Comment: обыйчный текст в тег p, ну к примеру:  Добрый день при значение value 0  в option и добрый вечер при значение value 1 в option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const it = $('#innte-text');
  let val = '';
 
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value !== 'Не выбраро'){
      $('#innte-text').text(this.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="Не выбраро">Выбрать приветствие</option>
  <option value="Доброе утро">Доброе утро!</option>
  <option value="Добрый день">Добрый день!</option>
  <option value="Добрый вечер">Добрый вечер!</option>
</select>
<p id="innte-text"></p>
```